# Android text to speech - change accent for language

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am developing an application for text to speech converter and in that, I want to provide options for selecting accent like English-us, English-UK etc. I am unsure that is it possible by programmatically? Give your suggestions.

Comment: Yes it is possible.There are many diffrent locales available.. u will have to set an UI for making selection of locales.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and very easy too you may fork my code and change eng-us to eng-uk in the code
https://github.com/karandeepdps/TTS-in-c-c-/releases/tag/v1